# How to set up RubyMine so that |tab| will trigger completion or indent depending on context?

Tags: rubymine

Is there a way to set up RubyMine so that if the cursor is right after a symbol, pressing |tab| will trigger autocompletion, but if it's not, pressing |tab| will indent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of customization can only be accomplished by writing a plugin.